# Redirect to other subdomain with single login?

Tags: wordpress, single-sign-on, keycloak

I want to know how to open wordpress login page for `keycloak` authentication. I have to use single-sign-on like google using `keycloak`& `wordpress` plugin.

Comment: Does wordpress support OIDC or SAML in order to act as an identity provider? Then https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_identity_broker

Comment: Thank you for help. wordpress supports OIDC or SAML through plugin. I  checked some plugins like miniorange but they are redirecting keycloak's login page or it's own login page, while i want to use wordpress's login page.... so any plugin for this requirement?

Comment: So you want keycloak to act as an identity broker? I guess the plugins you talk about are for configuring an external identity provider to access WordPress. Here you want it the other way, WordPress itself to be the idp. So take care with that.